# One radiator in my house is cold I bleed it got the air out, checked TRV the pin is not stuck but still won’t heat up like the other

Tags: radiator

Radiator is cold after I bleed it water comes out fine, check the TRV and the pin is fine moves in and out fine it still no heat. All of the other radiators are hot

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se], please take the [tour] to see how things work a little differently here. When you're done, please [edit] your question to include more info like, is this water or steam, what floor is the radiator on, what's the plumbing layout, where is this in relation to other radiators. Also, please actually _ask a question_ not just make some statements.

Comment: That doesn't totally rule out the TRV, but does rule out the head. Replacement of the complete valve *may* be necessary, but not as a first step. Has it always been like this? Is it stone cold top snd bottom, or does a little bit of it get a little warm?

Comment: Also I worked somewhere where the radiators at the top never worked properly. They needed bleeding every day, and still never got a flow, but bleeding with the system on got some hot water in there. Did you bleed with the system hot or cold, and if you bled with it hot, how hot did the radiator get then?

Answer (score 1):

Check the lockshield valve at the other end of the radiator.  It should be open a little, but not so much that this one radiator "steals" all the hot water from the other radiators.  The lockshield valve usually has a plastic cap, which pulls off.  Then you need to find a spanner that fits, or use pliers, to turn it.

If the lockshield valve is already open, the radiator may be blocked with sludge.